# I Need Help Converting a simple Coldfusion Script to Coldfusion Tag

Tags: function, coldfusion, cfc, cfml

I need help converting this ColdFusion Script to ColdFusion Tag.

```
public any function default(required rc) {
    // rc.varName = 'whatever';
}
```

Comment: Where are you having difficulty? And why do you want to change it to tags?

Comment: Hi, I am just very used to using the tag based format for ColdFusion.

Comment: OK, but back to my first (more relevant question): which part are you struggling with, and (didn't ask this): what have you tried so far. You know how to write a `<cffunction>`, right? And you must have seen script-based functions in the past. So which bits don't you "get" here?

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I am having trouble making rc required in the function. I can do this part
<cffunction name="getUsers" access="public" returntype="any">

</cffunction>
the part I am having trouble with is passing rc as required

Comment: Read: https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfargument

Comment: Cool: that makes it more clear. See Mark's answer: the missing piece of the puzzle for you is the `<cfargument>` tag. All of this should have come to you fairly quickly had you read the docs though? The docs page for `<cffunction>` (https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cffunction) make a point of ushering you to the page on working with components (https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Building+and+Using+ColdFusion+Components), and also mention `<cfargument>` sufficiently often as to make it obvious it's important info. Did you read the docs before starting this?

Comment: Adam, Yes I did read the docs, and it still didn't come to me. Hence the reason I requested help. Fortunately Mark was able to respond with a great answer.

Comment: When you have read docs state in your question - i.e. "I have read X doc page" - and (if relevant) highlight any particular section/paragraph (e.g. "I don't understand the text in paragraph Y" or "I don't see a section describing Z" or whatever). This demonstrates to readers that you have actually put effort in and are not just being lazy. (Unfortunately SO has many of the latter.)

Comment: Why, in the name of all that is holy, would you want to change a script based function into a tag based one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<cffunction name="default" access="public" returntype="any">
    <cfargument name="rc" required="true">
    <cfset arguments.rc.varname = "whatever">
</cffunction>
```

Comment: I've gotten into trouble in the past for not specifying the arguments scope.